# Add horizontal scrollbar to react table

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a css that disable all scrollbars and only a class with scrollbars active
then i have a table where vertical scrollbar appears and horizontal one don't appears.

I would like to have a horizontal scrollbar on the table.

this is css:

```
.rTable {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scrollbar-width: thin !important;
  scrollbar-color: transparent transparent !important;
}

.rTable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px !important;
}

.rTable::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
}

.rTable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #888 !important;
  border-radius: 6px !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
```

this is the table

```
<div className='shadowClass rTable'>
  <Table style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
    <thead className="table-primary">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Command</th>
        <th>Created at</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Running for</th>
        <th>Networks</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Local volumes</th>
        <th>Mounts</th>
        <th>Ports</th>
        <th>Labels</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {cResults.map((result) => (
        <tr key={result.ID}>
          <td>{result.Names}</td>
          <td>{result.Command}</td>
          <td>{result.CreatedAt}</td>
          <td>{result.Image}</td>
          <td>{result.Size}</td>
          <td>{result.RunningFor}</td>
          <td>{result.Networks}</td>
          <td>{result.State}</td>
          <td>{result.LocalVolumes}</td>
          <td>{result.Mounts}</td>
          <td>{result.Ports}</td>
          <td>{result.Labels}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
</div>
```

if i put a height the vertical scrollbar works but i need to horizontal one
if i remove this the horizontal one appears

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
```

i want only the horizontal one in the table.